# Angular 8: NullInjectorError - No provider for HighContrastModeDetector

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I am trying to implement Angular Material's Datatable and when I run the Localhost I end up with the following error in the console.

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[A11yModule -> HighContrastModeDetector]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[A11yModule -> HighContrastModeDetector]: NullInjectorError: 
No provider for HighContrastModeDetector!
```

I am also getting a warning that the Angular Material version (8.2.3) does not match the Angular CDK version (9.1.3). Are they related and also how would I match both versions. It is unable to find Angular Material core theme which might be related to the versions being different? I can share some code if needed. All help is appreciated!

Comment: angular cdk and material needs to be in the same version